# CSS custom design not applied after upgrading my magento

Tags: css, upgrade, magento-1.9.3.3

I upgraded magento to the newest version 1.9.3.3 and now it doesn't apply the custom css. 
I cleared the cache, checked the htaccess file and permissions. All fine and it was working before the upgrading.

So what can I do so that the custom css will be applied?

Comment: run upgrade/deploy/cache commands in sequence and delete cache manually

Comment: Ok I did this but the css is still not applied.

Answer (score 1):

How the custom css are applied?
If you add the custom css on new file declared on core files (bad practice), maybe the update procedure deleted the changes..

You should declare a new child theme and extend it with the changes you need

Comment: Added them with xml for the site.`<reference name="head">
<action method="addCss">
<stylesheet>css/stylesHomepage.css</stylesheet>
</reference>`

Comment: Where did you add this?